# Sylius - return validation messages on product save

Tags: symfony, sylius, sylius-1.3, sylius-resource

when I use the `sylius.factory.product` here https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/book/products/products.html

## Adding Product

```
/** @var ProductFactoryInterface $productFactory **/
$productFactory = $this->get('sylius.factory.product');

/** @var ProductInterface $product */
$product = $productFactory->createNew();
$product->setName('T-Shirt');
$product->setCode('00001');
$product->setSlug('t-shirt');

/** @var RepositoryInterface $productRepository */
$productRepository = $this->get('sylius.repository.product');

$productRepository->add($product);
```

and set the value of Code (has unique identifier) to a value already exists I get an exception I want to get the validation message "Product code must be unique." message provided by sylius 
How to get this done?

Comment: how are you calling this code? this seems as a job for Symfony's Form validation

Comment: I just need to add product with basic data (name, price, stock) then this code should(will) go in the service passing the dataParams

Comment: to me it just seems as a job for Validator https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Symfony Validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) for this. Set the constraint on your entity:

```
# config/validator/validation.yaml
App\Entity\Product:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [code]
            message: 'Product code must be unique'
```

And then call `validate()` on `Validator` service:

```
public function productMethod(
    ProductFactoryInterface $productFactory, 
    ValidatorInterface $validator
) {
    /** @var ProductFactoryInterface $productFactory **/
    $productFactory = $this->get('sylius.factory.product');

    /** @var ProductInterface $product */
    $product = $productFactory->createNew();
    $product->setName('T-Shirt');
    $product->setCode('00001');
    $product->setSlug('t-shirt');

    $errors = $validator->validate($product);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        $errorsString = (string) $errors;
        return $errorsString;
    }

    // ...do something else
}
```